# Do bubbles splash downward?

Tags: everyday-life, bubbles

When a solid ball drops into water, the kinetic energy of the ball pushes water upwards into what we call a splash:

[image]

**Does a similar effect occur when bubbles 'drop' upwards from the water into the air?**

*Note that this question was translated into English by my father, who is the one typing it. I'm eight years old and [I don't use SE unsupervised](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1693/move-a-question-to-a-new-user).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its far less pronounced when a bubble comes out of the surface of a liquid. You can see this in boiling water. Hover, in a bubble, the gas is confined to its space, and when it leaves the surface of the liquid, it expands (popping of a bubble) and pushes the liquid down slightly. As such, there isn't a splash which occurs that anyone can see without using specialised instruments, as the bubble has not very much air. Also, as the bubble rises, it does not have much kinetic energy (unless the liquid is boiling) to create a splash that can be seen.

Comment: Thank you. Now that I know of the need for specialized equipment we will search for slow-motion videos of the phenomenon.